# difference between expo version and expo sdk version

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am learning react native mobile development using expo. I am finding it difficult to understand the difference between expo and expo sdk. Can anyone please tell me the difference between these two commands provided below.  The first command returns output as 6 whereas the second command returns output as 50.

```
expo --version
6.3.10

npm show expo version
50.0.4
```

Comment: Hi Mike, 
Thanks for your response ... I might have installed it globally sometime before.. Can you please tell me how does it make the difference in these commands. I am running both these commands in the same general directory (My documents folder) not inside any project directory. Then how come both the commands return different output. Please explain. Thanks !!!

Comment: Note that `npm shows` you the version for the _package_ whereas the expo executable is actually `@expo/cli` and has its own version number. The real question is why you get 6.3.10, when the current version of the `expo` cli is 0.17.3

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. Thats strange if the current version is 0.17... how come mine is showing 6 !!!! I believe the version which shows as 6 is what I installed globally ? 
Is there a way to uninstall it ?

Comment: you can try an `npm uninstall -g expo`, which will remove the global install if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expo --version is used to check the version of the Expo CLI installed globally on your system. npm show expo version is project specific and checks the version of the Expo SDK in your current project directory.